# How to execute multiple find & replace in a google doc with a csv file?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using Google doc to write an essay, which contains tons of traditional Chinese characters. To publish in Japan, I have to change all of them into Japanese Kanji characters.

I tried "replaceText" as below,

```
function BodyReplace() {
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.replaceText("賴", "頼"); 
  body.replaceText("國", "国"); 
  body.replaceText("遲", "遅"); 
}
```

but I have to add hundreds of entries. I heard that I can create a csv file as a database, and execute search & replace in a Google Doc. I somehow created a csv file like

```
賴,頼
國,国
遲,遅
```

, and I don't know how to get the content from a csv file and do the search & replace.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution:

If the csv is in your google drive,

- Get csv from drive
- Parse it to a 2D array
- Loop through the array

#### Snippet:

```
var csvAsString = DriveApp.getFileById("/*CSV FILE ID*/").getBlob().getDataAsString();
var arr2d = Utilities.parseCsv(csvAsString);
for(var i=0; i<arr2d.length;++i){
  body.replaceText(arr2d[i][0], arr2d[i][1]); 
}
```

#### References:

- [Official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)
- [Utilities lib](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parseCsv(String))

Comment: Thank you! I want to do the same thing to the footnotes too, so I amended part of the codes. It works fine but longer time is needed than executing the body part.

var footnote = doc.getFootnotes();
for(var j in footnote)
for(var i=0; i<arr2d.length;++i){  
footnote[j].getFootnoteContents().replaceText(arr2d[i][0],arr2d[i][1]);